# Https page does not open from local server

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

I have purchased and installed an SSL certificate on IIS on windows server 2016. I can access the website successfully from outside (https://example.com) but when I login to the server that hosts the website open a browser and type in the (https://example.com) the site does not open and I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically means that the hostname is not accessible from the server. 
I will try to ping hostname and see if that succeeds. If it fails, then its a network configuration that you need to review. This is a very common scenario.

If the SSL binding is configured on **All Unassigned** IP, then you can browse the site locally via https://localhost or https://Server-name